# Android DatePicker- GregorianCalendar - 00:00:00 UTC - getTimeInMillis()

Tags: android, date, datetime, android-studio, calendar

How do I set the Time of the GregorianCalendar to 00:00:00 UTC?

Because the following returns a Date at 10:00pm:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ,0 ,0, 0);
editor.putString("auswahldatum", String.valueOf(cal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000))
      .apply();
Log.i("Kalender", String.valueOf(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Calendar's `Calendar.getInstance(timeZone)` method it already return of new object of gregorian calendar. You can create it for example like this one:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(timezone);
```

Or

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ,0 ,0, 0);
cal.setTime(date);
cal.setTimeZone(timezone);
```

Actually you must set time zone after time setting